# Jquery UI Autocomplete - Way to show preferred

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-autocomplete

I'm a newbie programmer / designer trying to configure jquery ui autocomplete. I have it working, using a javascript object (array). The array contains retailer stores that we are directing our customers to. We have certain stores that are preferred and so we would like for them to come up earlier than other stores but I don't really know how to filter them into the result or if it is even possible.

I want "Widget Store 4" to appear first if anyone types in "Widget". Here's the jquery code:

```
var widgetstores = [ 
{label: "Widget Store 1", value: "1001" }, {label: "Widget Store 2", value: "1002" }, {label: "Widget Store 3", value: "1003" }, {label: "Widget Store 4", value: "1004" }, {label: "Widget Store 5", value: "1005" }, {label: "Widget Store 6", value: "1006" }
]

 $(function() {     
                $('#tags').autocomplete({
                    minLength: 3,
                    source: widgetstores,
                    focus: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#tags').val(ui.item.label);
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#tags').val(ui.item.label);
                        $('#customer_num').val(ui.item.value);                      
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                    return $( "<li></li>" )
                        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                        .appendTo( ul );
                };
            });
```

Comment: Please remember to mark your code as being code, so that it gets the nice formatting and helps reading ! (select the text and click the 0101 button)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what AutoComplete library you're using, but it looks like:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

That library does **not** sort the items for you automatically. It uses the order of the items passed to the script, and filters from that. So if your items are in the order you want them before you pass to the autocomplete it should use that order.

Update:

```
var widgetstores = [ 
{label: "Widget Store 4", value: "1004" }, {label: "Widget Store 1", value: "1001" }, {label: "Widget Store 2", value: "1002" }, {label: "Widget Store 3", value: "1003" }, {label: "Widget Store 5", value: "1005" }, {label: "Widget Store 6", value: "1006" }
]
```